# What is the lab wort pH of Rye Malt

Tags: mash, rye, ph

I am planning a brew where Rye malt is a considerable component of the grist. I am trying to predict my mash pH by taking the weighted lab wort pH contributions of each of my malts, and accounting for residual alkalinity.

I have read that rye malt, like wheat malt has tendency opposite to barley, in that it increases pH. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a malt analysis or other reliable information that would give even an estimate of lab wort pH for rye malt. Does anyone happen to know this value (even roughly?) or have a resource that might be useful? The supplier of the rye malt in this case is Canada Malting.

Answer (score 2):

Rye malt is generally similar to wheat with a projected distilled water mash ph of 6.04 for a %100 wheat grist.

Select "Wheat" in your water profile calculator, and mash ph estimator.